# Use FFmpeg to split video into multiple scenes

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-encoding

I am trying to use FFmpeg for splitting a video into multiple supposedly single-scene sub-videos using the `scenecut` feature and threshold. I found the following command on SE:

```
ffmpeg -i myVideo.mp4 -y -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -prese6t:v fast -deinterlace -x264opts min-keyint=15:keyint=1000:scenecut=20 -b:v 2000k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f segment -segment_format mp4 -segment_format_options movflags=empty_moov+frag_keyframe+default_base_moof+skip_trailer+faststart /home/1/output%%05d.mp4
```

But the following command doesn't work for me and shows error:

```
Unrecognized option 'prese6t:v'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Is there any changes since the last FFmpeg? I'm using the latest version.

Comment: Anyone landing on this question/post [may find this useful](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/28613/how-to-extract-each-video-scene-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@K7AAY is on the right track. The option label is `preset`. The output filename mask should be `output%05d`

But aside from the syntax errors, there are a couple of fundamental issues as well. Fragmented MP4 options are meant for when the segments are packaged within a single container file. The segment muxer emits multiple files so the MP4 muxer fragmentation can be skipped. Also, segment_time should be specified, and with a very low value, else GOPs of size less than the default value (2s) will be combined in some segments.

Command should be

```
ffmpeg -y -i myVideo.mp4 -vf yadif \
       -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset:v fast \
       -x264opts min-keyint=15:keyint=1000:scenecut=20 -b:v 2000k \
       -c:a aac -b:a 128k \
       -f segment -segment_format mp4 -segment_time 0.01 -segment_format_options movflags=faststart \
       /home/1/output%05d.mp4
```

Comment: Still I get error: `[segment @ 00000210c1e1f040] Could not parse format options list 'faststart'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --`

Comment: btw, can I shrink the command? Maybe we can just copy codec `-c copy`? Most important thing for me is to play around the sensitivity of the scenecut threshold

Comment: Corrected cmd..

Comment: thanks. It works. One question is that now it takes a long time. My eventual goal is just to save an image from each scene, say middle frame of that image, instead of encoding and saving the scene video. Is there a faster way to achieve that? Here is my new question: https://superuser.com/questions/1337709

Answer (score 1):

After replacing `prese6t:v`
with `preset:v`
because there's no "prese6t" option for ffmpeg

replace `output%%05d.mp4`
with `output5d.mp4`

as ffmpeg is rejecting `output%%05d.mp4` as an invalid file name.

Comment: No, the problem is the error. Please look at my updated question.

Comment: No, that also didn't work: `[mp4 @ 000001adb348a740] Invalid segment filename template 'output%%05d.mp4'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --`

Comment: Corrected, see answer.