# FFmpeg scene detection and scenecut

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-encoding

This is a follow-up question from my previous question posted [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/1337160). So basically using FFmpeg, I'm trying to detect scenes after choosing a good `scenecut` threshold, and grab a single representative frame out of each scene.

Right now, the below scene detection command we already have, saves the detected scenes on disk, which unfortunately takes a long time:

```
ffmpeg -y -i myVideo.mp4 -vf yadif \
       -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset:v fast \
       -x264opts min-keyint=15:keyint=1000:scenecut=20 -b:v 2000k \
       -c:a aac -b:a 128k \
       -f segment -segment_format mp4 -segment_time 0.01 -segment_format_options movflags=faststart \
       /home/1/output%05d.mp4
```

My eventual goal is to identify the scenes, and only save a single frame out of that scene as an image (say middle frame of that scene) instead of encoding and saving the whole scene videos. Is there a fast way to achieve that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/40688062/5726027 and 2nd part from https://stackoverflow.com/q/34962426/5726027

Comment: @Gyan Very useful. But `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vsync 0 -vf select='gt(scene\,0.4)' -f image2 img-%04d.png` doesn't work for me, and shows me error: `Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`

Comment: You should run cmd from first link and then prepare text file as shown in 2nd link.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan. Assuming  I need only the first frame of scene, what would be a single-run command (not two commands)?

Answer (score 3):

This should work for getting the first frame of the shot.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter:v "select=gt(scene\,0.5)" -vsync vfr output/frame%d.jpg
```