# Find different scenes with FFmpeg and concat them to a new clip

Tags: video, ffmpeg

It seems possible to find different scenes, or at least differences between frames if I have understood the concept correct. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675529/using-ffmpeg-how-to-do-a-scene-change-detection-with-timecode), for example . Also, [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1337160/use-ffmpeg-to-split-video-into-multiple-scenes)  seems to extract scenes, but to single files.

I would like to extract 3 scenes from `input.mp4` that are 2 seconds long, and the output should be a `.gif`. The total `.gif` duration should be 6 seconds long.